# Use struct.pack() to create bitfield

Tags: python, struct, binary

As far as I can see there are only format options for creating one or multiple bytes when using `struct.pack()`. I would like to create a field containing, for example, 4 bits, or just one. How could I do that?
I know that there is a module called `bitarray`, but I would like to solve this using `struct.pack()`

Comment: struct just allows a full number of bytes. So everything below 8 bit you have to do manually. To combine two 4 bit values to one byte just make `var_8bit = var1_4bit << 4 + var2_4bit`. Otherwise you need some lower structure like bitarray

Comment: I didn't think about using bit shifting, I think that will do. Thanks!